# Why do we say "well-read" instead of "well-reading"?

Tags: grammar

I have a question about the form of "well-read." Why don't we say "well-reading" instead? We people read, but not are read. There are many examples of "people are well read" online, but I wonder whether it comes from.  Another phrase is "short-lived" love. Why do you say that? Is there a way to explain these two phrases in the term of grammar? Thanks in advance.

Gloria

Comment: Because someone doesn't have to actually be reading at the time for you to call them "well read".  It rather implies something about their past reading activities.

Comment: See [definition 2.1 at ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/read).

Comment: well-skilled, well-schooled, well-versed, well-educated; well built; a well-lived life; well-born, well-known.  And so forth.

Comment: Never heard anyone say that someone was *well-mannering*, *well-knowing*, or *well-breeding*, the past participle is always used; **well-mannered**, **well-known** and **well-bred**. The adverb "well" describes how "good" someone or something is

Comment: There is, however, **well-meaning**.

Comment: @HotLicks that might actually be the basis for an interesting question, **well-meant** and **well-meaning** mean the same. There's also **well-being**,  I should be more careful before proclaiming rules.

Answer (score 1):

People *are* read, that is, informed or educated through reading. The OED flags this verb sense of *read* as obsolete, and the adjectival usage as chiefly predicative, but *well-read* has become a fixed expression.

> 1a. Of a person: experienced, versed, or informed in a subject by reading…  Used simply and with adverbs; now chiefly in *well-read*
>
> b.  Informed by reading, acquainted with books or literature, learned. Chiefly in predicative use…. Now only with modifying adverbs; chiefly in *well-read*

Similarly, *lived* is a perfectly legitimate adjective indicating that something has a certain kind or length of life, but the OED notes it is used *chiefly as the second element in compounds*. In other words, it's uncommon to describe a life as simply *lived* (which seems tautological), but it could be *long-lived*, *self-lived*, *soft-lived*, and so on.

There are any number of these fixed expressions; for instance, you wouldn't describe a *long-winded* person as merely *winded* if he were briefer, or a *long-lasted* television show as simply *lasted* if it only ran for ten episodes. The attribute component of the compound may also be necessary in many cases where the main adjective or participle does have a contemporary meaning; an *informed* electorate is rather the opposite of an *ill-informed electorate*, and a *high-born woman* is equally as *born* as a *low-born* woman— in the main sense, if not any others.

Other than that, I see little grammatical difference between being *short-staffed* and being *very tall*, or between being *hard-earned* and being *highly taxed*.